# Error expected expression before ")" token in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write this program to return the denormal values but I am getting an error shown below. Can you anyone help me fix this error:

```
support.c: In function 'is_denormal':
support.c:50:34: error: expected expression before ')' token
```

In this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int is_denormal( double x)
{

   union dp_item N1;   
   N1.drep = x;

   union dp_item N2;
   N2.drep = x;



   N1.irep = absolute(N1.drep, x*);
   N1.irep = N1.irep >> 52;
   if (N1.irep == 0x0ULL)
   {

      N2.irep = N2.irep << 12;
      if (N2.irep != 0x0ULL)
      {return 1;}
      return 0;

   }
   else {return 0;}


}
```

Here is the absolute function:

```
double absolute( double x, double y* )
{
   union dp_item N;   
   N.drep = x;

   N.irep = N.irep & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
   return N.drep;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `0x0ULL` supposed to be? That's not a hex value.

Comment: @ChrisHayes, that's an `unsigned long long` literal `0`.

Comment: @ChrisHayes unsigned long long

Comment: Why did you post an error referencing line 54 instead of posting the error from the code that you did post?  It makes life unnecessarily hard for those who would help you. Please, post the errors from the code you post!

Comment: @CarlNorum Oh, I see, thanks. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 9):

This line:

```
N1.irep = absolute(N1.drep, x*);
```

Has invalid syntax.  What's that `*` for?

Comment: It is a pointer for the second parameter in the absolute function I added above.

Comment: @Ratman2050: `x` is a `double`, not a pointer. And the dereferencing operator is prefix, not postfix.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
N1.irep = absolute(N1.drep, x*);
```

if your are considering `x*` as pointer x then you are wrong you must write it as prefix `*x`.